# How to select the the group of objects with the highest total value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables like this:

Objects (NumId is *Primary key*)

| NumId | Object_category | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | permanent | 20 |
| 2 | borrowed | 30 |
| 3 | borrowed | 10 |

Collection (ColName is *Primary Key*)

| ColName |
| --- |
| collection_alpha |
| collection_betha |

Borrowed

(NumObj is *Foreign Key/Primary Key* referring Object table, and *Collection_name* is *Foreign Key* referring Collection table)

| NumObj | Collection_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | collection_alpha |
| 2 | collection_betha |
| 3 | collection betha |

The query I need to do is: "Which collections (excluding the permanent) have the highest total cost of borrowed objects?"

my current attempt (that doesn't work):

```
SELECT ColName FROM Colecao
WHERE (
   SELECT MAX((SUM(Price)) FROM Objects AS Num
   JOIN Borrowed ON NumObj = Objects.NumId
   JOIN Collection ON ColName = Collection_name
   WHERE Num > COUNT(NumId) FROM Objects 
   WHERE Object_category = "permanent"
);
```

It returns message: "syntax error"

Comment: *It returns message: "syntax error"* - your query has two WHERE clauses and a FROM after the last WHERE clause, what did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Which collections [...] have the highest total cost of borrowed objects?"

```
select
    b.Collection_name,
    sum(o.price) Worth
from
    Objects o
    inner join Borrowed b on b.NumObj = o.NumId
where
    o.Object_category = 'borrowed'
group by
    b.Collection_name
order by
    sum(o.price) desc
```

gives you a list of all collections ordered descending by the overall worth of the borrowed objects. You could add `limit 1` to show the top item of the list.

But imagine there are two collections that happen to have the same total worth. They would **both** have *"the highest total cost of borrowed objects"*, so both should be returned. The above query with `limit 1` would omit one of them.

In this case we could [rank](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#built_in_window_functions) the collections according to their worth, and return all rows with rank = 1.

```
select
    *
from
    (
    select
        *,
        rank() over (order by Worth desc) rnk
    from
        (
        select
            b.Collection_name,
            sum(o.price) Worth
        from
            Objects o
            inner join Borrowed b on b.NumObj = o.NumId
        where
            o.Object_category = 'borrowed'
        group by
            b.Collection_name
        ) collections
    ) collections_ranked
where
    rnk = 1
order by
    Collection_name
```

Alternatively, we could set up a [CTE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) and express the same thing like this:

```
with
    collections as (
        select
            b.Collection_name,
            sum(o.price) Worth
        from
            Objects o
            inner join Borrowed b on b.NumObj = o.NumId
        where
            o.Object_category = 'borrowed'
        group by
            b.Collection_name
    )
select
    Collection_name,
    Worth
from
    collections
where
    Worth = (select max(worth) from collections)
order by
    Collection_name
```